# How to add custom class when I have this problem?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

[1][input.css in my tailwind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzQED.jpg)

I can't add custom class. There seem to be three problems here and I don't know what the yellow line is.

I have installed it several times but it did not help. I checked all the routes and there was no problem. All parts work well except this part

Comment: It's a warning from VSCode in that its CSS parser does not recognize the `@tailwind` rules. The messages can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's just a warning from Visual Studio Code that it doesn't recognize `@tailwind` rule.

You can use [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) extension for Visual Studio Code. This is an official extension that's pretty helpful and will actually fix these warnings.